# MYSQL Query Using HAVING Not Work Correctly

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, having-clause

```
SELECT user_data_fields.user_id, CONCAT(",", GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(user_data_fields.field_id, "-",user_data_fields.value)), ",") AS var, survey_answers.question_id, survey_answers.answer 
FROM user_data_fields 
JOIN survey_answers ON survey_answers.user_id = user_data_fields.user_id 
WHERE survey_answers.question_id IN (328,329,330,331,332,333,334,335,336,337,338,339,340,341,342,343,344,345,346,347,348,349)
GROUP BY user_data_fields.user_id,survey_answers.question_id 
HAVING 
    var LIKE "%,5-3,%" AND 
    var LIKE "%,4-180801,%" OR 
     var LIKE "%,4-190801,%" OR 
     var LIKE "%,4-310101,%" OR 
     var LIKE "%,4-420501,%" OR 
     var LIKE "%,4-170701,%"
```

I Want to select where `var LIKE "%,5-3,%"` And one Of Other Conditions 
Now It Works But Something is Strange that first after `AND` not return in array results 
i mean this condition `var LIKE "%,4-180801,%"` but others work correctly and return results 
Can Anyone Help Me Please.

Comment: Why the first AND in `var LIKE "%,5-3,%" AND 
    var LIKE "%,4-180801,%"`?

Comment: i want first condition `var LIKE "%,5-3,%"` to be exit and one of the others

Comment: When mixing AND and OR, always force order of evaluation with parenthesis, if for no  other reason than to make your intent clear. `A AND B OR C OR D` is equivalent to `(A AND B) OR C OR D`

Comment: `HAVING 
    (var LIKE "%,5-3,%") AND 
    (var LIKE "%,4-180801,%" OR 
     var LIKE "%,4-190801,%" OR 
     var LIKE "%,4-310101,%" OR 
     var LIKE "%,4-420501,%" OR 
     var LIKE "%,4-170701,%")` Did u mean like this it return no results

Comment: In order to "work correctly", you need to learn how to write proper SQL.  You can't expect your program to spit out the correct result if you write query with whatever syntax you want.

Comment: And In your opinion what is the proper SQL for this query

Answer (score 1):

Try this way..

Filter and then group.

```
SELECT 
    user_data_fields.user_id
    ,CONCAT(",", GROUP_CONCAT(field_id_value), ",") AS var
    ,survey_answers.question_id, survey_answers.answer 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            *
            ,CONCAT(user_data_fields.field_id, "-",user_data_fields.value) field_id_value   
        FROM 
            user_data_fields 
        where 
        (
                CONCAT(user_data_fields.field_id, "-",user_data_fields.value) like '%,5-3,%' AND 
                CONCAT(user_data_fields.field_id, "-",user_data_fields.value) like '%,4-180801,%'
                ,...
                ...
        )
    ) u
JOIN 
    (
        select 
            * 
        from 
            survey_answers s 
        WHERE 
            question_id IN (328,329,330,331,332,333,334,335,336,337,338,339,340,341,342,343,344,345,346,347,348,349) 
    ) s

ON s.user_id = u.user_id 

GROUP BY u.user_id,s.question_id
```

Comment: it returns empty result

Comment: your condition is like this.. are you sure whether first one is AND and rest are OR ?

    var LIKE "%,5-3,%" AND 
    var LIKE "%,4-180801,%" OR 
     var LIKE "%,4-190801,%" OR 
     var LIKE "%,4-310101,%" OR 
     var LIKE "%,4-420501,%" OR 
     var LIKE "%,4-170701,%"


in that case it should be   in the subquery I gave you.

 var LIKE "%,5-3,%" AND ( rest of the OR conditions   )

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this does what you want:

```
HAVING
    SUM(udf.field_id = 5 and udf.value = 3) > 0
    AND SUM(
        udf.field = 4 
        AND udf.value in (180801, 190801, 310101, 420501, 170701)
    ) > 0
```

Where `udf` is the alias for table `user_data_fields.field_id`.

That is: instead of trying to filter on the results of the string aggregation function, use conditional `SUM()`s. The above query filters out groups of records based on the values of the `(field_id, value)` tuple:

- at least one record in the group must have tuple `(5, 3)`
- at least one record in the group must satisfy the other conditional expression

Comment: it returns empty result